# Scrolling HTML 5 Canvas in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, canvas

I have got a canvas tag in a page wrapped within a div.
In order to show the canvas in IE, I'm using the [excanvas](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/) script from Google.

I'd like to be able to scroll the contents of the canvas, since it's supposed to be wider and taller than the viewport (the div).

I have defined the following styles:

- The div overflow is scroll or auto
- The canvas position is relative

In Firefox, I then get a scrolling viewport of the cancas, but in Internet Explorer (7), the canvas does not move.

Does anybody know whether it's possible to get a scrolling canvas in IE, and if yes how can it be done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to set the scroll property on scroll only.
But not sure, could you put a bit of code for us to see it?